# Parsing google calendar in xcode

Tags: ios, rss, google-calendar-api, nsxmlparser

I am attempting to add an event schedule to an iOS / xcode app that I am working on.  I have been able to parse the google calendar feed using Michael Waterfalls' code at https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser but I have not been able to replace the date the post was created with the date the event is scheduled.

The feed url is placed in the RootViewController.m file and I am using this feed http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/firstpentecostalchurch.com_e2hia2v3bc766ff9397qu3eqa8%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic

I am sure this is easy, I must be missing something as the heavy lifting is already done.

Comment: I discovered a short work around by using feedburner. After you seup feedburner with your calendars link and append the api options do the following: in your browsers address bar replace the word dashboard with event.  check both the future events and include event date in title boxes.  Not as neat but very easy.

Comment: To create the perfect feed use the above along with feedburners convert to RSS2.0.  This replaced the post date with the event date in the feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using Calendar API v3 instead as GData feeds are deprecated https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_protocol

Comment: Good suggestion, just requires a re-write of my code.  I am currently using the RSS feed from my calendar to pull events.

Comment: The new API has a set of client libraries that would do the parsing for you: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/downloads

Answer (score 0):

The event dates you are looking for don't have an XML tag associated with them.  That's to be expected because they aren't part of the RSS specification. The event dates are embedded in the text of the <summary> and <content> tags, which contain HTML.

It appears that the event dates at least have consistent patterns (one for recurring events and another for single events).  For example, single event summaries seem to appear at the beginning in a long date format prefixed by a "When: ".

You could use regular expressions to pull out the dates, but you might have to add logic for the recurring events to calculate all the the specific dates.  And if the maintainer of the feed changes their format, your interface will break.  You can try to anticipate that somewhat by looking for multiple different date patterns, but that only goes so far.

Comment: Thanks, that would explain my difficulty to date.  I think I will try out your suggestion.  I know I can code recurring events to present as single by adding an api parameter to the link I am using (singleevents). Would you have any guidance on how I should approach pulling the dates with regular expressions?

Comment: Do a search on NSRegularExpression and you'll find some examples. And I forgot about NSDataDetector. That's worth a look also.